# How would say something like "I hate to break it to you, but..." in Japanese?

Tags: phrase-requests

"I hate to break it to you, but..." or "Sorry, but..."
For example: "Sorry, but I don't like cake" or "I hate to break it to you, but I didn't like your performance". What popped into my head was to say "ごめんけど", but I've never heard anyone say that and thus I'm sure it's 100% wrong.
I'm curious as to how to say something like this, even if I'll never use it, but I haven't been able to find anything substantial online yet.
An example sentence would be helpful too.

Comment: わるいけど might be more appropriate here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can say:

- 悪いけど / 悪いですが
- 申し訳ないけど / 申し訳ありませんが
- 残念だけど / 残念ではありますが
- 言いたくないけど / 申し上げづらいのですが

ごめんけど is ungrammatical because けど needs the dictionary form of a verb/adjective/copula. But you can say "ごめん、けど、…" as if were two sentences.